# How to convert a JavaScript array to an object with a specified structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

I have an array like the example `logicData` below.

I want to pass this array to a function that returns an object like the `returnObject` below.

In addition, using the returned object, I need to re-create the original `logicData` array.

Please anyone help me out. Thanks in Advance.

```js
// array
var logicData = [
  {
    details: {
      name: "User-1",
      id: 1,
      age: "38",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Accountant",
  },
  {
    details: {
      name: "User-2",
      id: 2,
      age: "55",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Sales executive",
  },
  {
    details: {
      name: "User-3",
      id: 3,
      age: "25",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Engineer",
  },
  {
    details: {
      name: "User-4",
      id: 4,
      age: "29",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Engineer",
  },
  {
    details: {
      name: "User-5",
      id: 5,
      age: "32",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Sales executive",
  }
]
```

How to convert the array to below format

```js
// require object formate
const returnObject = {
  first: {
    details: {
      name: "User-1",
      id: "1",
      age: "38",
    },
    company: "XYX",
    position: "Accountant",
  },
  second: {
    first: {
      details: {
        name: "User-2",
        id: 2,
        age: "55",
      },
      company: "XYX",
      position: "Sales executive",
    },
    second: {
      first: {
        details: {
          name: "User-3",
          id: 3,
          age: "25",
        },
        company: "XYX",
        position: "Engineer",
      },
      second: {
        first: {
          details: {
            name: "User-4",
            id: 4,
            age: "29",
          },
          company: "XYX",
          position: "Engineer",
        },
        second: {
          details: {
            name: "User-5",
            id: 5,
            age: "32",
          },
          company: "XYX",
          position: "Sales executive",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your converted format is not valid JavaScript. Please update it.

Comment: @terrymorse I'm not sure on that, I got this format from the backend side and backend supporting that,  could you please let me know, anyhow is it possible to achieve that JSON Object. Thanks

Comment: I’m sure. Missing comma, semicolons where there should be commas.

Comment: ooh, that is I think my mistake
it should be

Comment: I converted your invalid object to a valid one and revised the question. Please review.

Comment: How do you decide `AND` and `OR` of action key ?

Comment: First of all you need to find a pattern for that format, is there any other information about it or you just have the format?

You can start by using the returned object as a mock to fill your values, set all values to null, then loop through the initial array and fill the corresponding element on the hierarchy.

Comment: "AND" & "OR" I removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for converting structures like `logicData` to `returnObject`, you can use/reuse the following function:

```js
function convertArrToObj(arr){
    let res = arr[arr.length - 1];
    for(let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        res = {
            first: arr[i - 1],
            second: res,
        }
    }
    return res;
}

convertArrToObj(logicData);
```

and for reverting the structures like `returnObject` back to `logicData` array structure, you can use/reuse this function:

```js
function revertObjToArr(obj){
    const res = [];
    let temp = obj;
    while("second" in temp){
        res.push(temp.first);
        temp = temp.second;
    }
    res.push(temp);
    return res;
}

revertObjToArr(returnObject);
```